# Implement two sortable lists in jquery-ui where one is hidden and is revealed after dragging over the title

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have two sortable lists linked together using `jquery-ui`.  One is hidden however and I'd like it to be shown when dragging an element from `List 1` over the title `List 2`.  Then without releasing the mouse, I'd like the elements in `List 2` to continue to sort.

The reveal does work, but the elements do not sort once the list is shown.  How do I go about implementing this?  Here is a link to the [js-fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k19zsa2g/5/)

To see what I mean, try dragging `Card 1` to the title `List 2`, and then to `Card 4` without releasing the mouse in the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be the problem is connected to CSS property `display: none`. In case you will change it to `visibility: hidden` it will work as you expecting

```js
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({
  connectWith: ".sortable",
  stop: function(ev,ui){
    console.log('done')
  },
});
      
$( "h3" ).droppable({
  over:function(ev, ui){
    var id = $(ev.target).next().css({visibility: 'visible'});
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: arial
}

.container {
  display:block
}


ul li {
  list-style-type:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <h3>List 1</h3>
  <ul class='sortable'>
    <li class='li-sortable'>Card 1</li>
    <li class='li-sortable'>Card 2</li>
    <li class='li-sortable'>Card 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class='container' >
  <h3>List 2</h3>
  <ul class='sortable' style='visibility:hidden'>
    <li class='li-sortable'>Card 4</li>
    <li class='li-sortable'>Card 5</li>
    <li class='li-sortable'>Card 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I needed to call `$( ".sortable" ).sortable('refresh');` in the `over`callback of `droppable`

```
$( "h3" ).droppable({
    over:function(ev, ui){
        var id = $(ev.target).next().show();
        $( ".sortable" ).sortable('refresh');
    }
 });
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4qu1nf6/)